# Как определить по какому из View было нажатие в кастомизированном ListView

Tags: java, android

Есть кастомизированный ListView c такой разметкой каждого элемента:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/id_icon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/del_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Адаптер

```
public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Icon> objects;

public IconAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Icon> icons) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = icons;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon, parent, false);
    }

    Icon p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_icon)).setText(String.valueOf(p.id));
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_icon)).setText(p.name);
    return view;
}

Icon getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Icon) getItem(position));
}
```

}

Каким образом можно узнать на какой View в строке нажал пользователь?

Comment: код покажите, адаптер и активити

Comment: @Kirill Stoianov, адаптер добавил. В активити нет важного

Comment: Устанавливать onClickListener не на листвью, а на каждый елемент в методе getView ?

Comment: @Kirill Stoianov, не понял идеи. Я думал в setOnItemClickListener как-то работать с родительским view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

1. Если действия должны быть разными, то лучше в адаптере, в getView повесить по слушателю отдельному на каждую вьюху.
2. Если действия схожи, то также там же вешайте слушатель на корневую вьюху элемента списка и определяйте в нем ID нажатой вьюхи
3. Повесьте слушатель снаружи адаптера (OnItemClickListener) и в нём определяйте ID нажатой вьюхи. Этот вариант самый негибкий. И, когда вы перейдёте с устаревшего ListView  на  RecyclerView вам придётся вернуться к п1 или п2

Comment: спасибо за конструктивный ответ. Подскажите, где можно почитать о решении моего вопроса по п.1/п2 ?

Comment: Да тут читать то и нечего... Вам нужно всего два метода класса `View` - `setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener)` и `getId()`

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи советую сделать так:

```
   ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("...", "нажат пункт №: " + i + " id: " + l);
        }
    });
```

Где: adapterView - экземпляр вашего адаптера.

View - экземпляр элемента списка.

i - его позиция.

l - его id.

У вас есть все для организация работы из под компонента приложения, не затрагивая дополнительно другие классы, не перебрасывая Context, и дополнительный экземпляр списка вашей бизнес логики, что не очень хорошо. 
Да и когда будете работать с RecyclerView хорошем тоном, будет организовать аналогичный callback для него.

Comment: В коде из вопроса id возращает позицию. Вообще значение id отличное от позиции возвращается из адаптеров, работающих с БД и значение его - id записи в БД. Id вью не возращается этим колбэком ни одним стандартным адаптером, насколько я помню.

Comment: В коде идет работа с ArrayList<Icon>.  Доступ к этому объекту есть и из Activity, вы можете по позиции узнать id данного объекта из этого же списка.